# How to prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) dF^n(x) = n \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) F^{n-1}(x) dF(x)$

Tags: probability, distributions, measure-theory

Let $F$ be a distribution function, and let $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real function.

I want to prove  $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) dF^n(x) = n \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) F^{n-1}(x) dF(x)$, where $dF$ means to take integral with respect to the distribution measure generated by distribution function $F$, and $F^n$ refers to $F \times \ldots \times F$.

We may assume that $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing.

If $F$ admits density $f$, then the question is easy since $F^n$ has density $nF(x)^{n-1} f(x)$. However, $F$ may not have a density, in which case I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote the probability measure associated with $F$ by $\mu$ so that $\mu(a, b] = F(b) - F(a)$ for $a < b$. Then the probability measure $\nu$ associated with $F^n$ is given by $\nu(A) = \int_A dF^n(x)$ for $A \in \mathscr{R}^1$.  The goal is to prove for any $g$ is non-negative or integrable with respect to $\nu$ (this is a natural condition imposed on the integrand that you didn't clearly stated) under the assumption $F$ is strictly increasing and continuous, it holds that
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}g(x)\nu(dx) = n\int_\mathbb{R}g(x)F^{n - 1}(x)\mu(dx). \tag{1}
\end{align}

By Theorem 16.11 in *Probability and Measure* (3rd edition) by Patrick Billingsley, to show $(1)$, it suffices to show that $\nu$ has density $nF^{n - 1}(x)$ with respect to $\mu$, that is, to show that for any $A \in \mathscr{R}^1$, it holds that
\begin{align}
\nu(A) = \int_AnF^{n - 1}(x)\mu(dx). \tag{2}
\end{align}

Because the linear Borel set $\mathscr{R}^1$ is generated by the class $\mathscr{I}$ consisting of intervals $(a, b]$, which is a $\pi$-system, if we can show that $\nu(a, b] = \int_a^bnF^{n - 1}(x)\mu(dx)$ holds for any $a < b$, then $(2)$ holds by Theorem 10.3 in *Probability and Measure*. Since $\nu(a, b] = \int_a^b dF^n(x) = F(b)^n - F(a)^n$, we eventually reduced the original problem to proving
\begin{align}
F(b)^n - F(a)^n = \int_a^b nF^{n - 1}(x)\mu(dx) = \int_a^bnF^{n - 1}(x)dF(x). \tag{3}
\end{align}
$(3)$ is almost trivial under the condition that $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing, which allows us to make the variable substitution $u = F(x)$ in the right-hand side of $(3)$, which gives
\begin{align}
\int_a^b nF^{n - 1}(x)dF(x) = \int_{F(a)}^{F(b)}nu^{n - 1}du = F(b)^n - F(a)^n.  
\end{align}

This completes the proof.

It should be pointed out this equality does not hold for general distribution function $F$.  For example, when $F$ is the distribution function of $X \sim B(1, 1/2)$. For this $F$ and $n = 2$,
\begin{align}
\nu(\mathbb{R}^1) = 1 \neq 2\int_\mathbb{R}F(x)dF(x) = 2 \times (0.5 \times 0.5 +  1 \times 0.5) = \frac{3}{2}. 
\end{align}

Comment: Nice set-up for the derivation. However, aren't you resorting to Theorem 16.10 rather than 16.11? The latter is the Scheffe's lemma.

Comment: @User1865345 It's 16.11 (beginning with "*If $\nu$ has density $\delta$ with respect to $\mu$*").  I am referring to the Third Edition.  It is not about Scheffe's lemma but basically guarantees if $\nu(A) = \int_A \delta d\mu$ then $\int_A fd\nu = \int_A f\delta d\mu$.

Comment: Yes. That is the one. The edition is different (2nd) - here 16.11 is Scheffe's lemma.

Comment: @User1865345 Next time probably I need to add the edition number because I quoted this book so often :).

Comment: Anyway, nice answer as usual. If someone has the book, they can figure it out the indexing of the theorems you cited - no issue. +1.

Comment: By the way, to my understanding, Scheffe's lemma is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma.  Is Theorem 16.11 also known as Scheffe's lemma?

Comment: To be precise, Billingsley called it _Scheffe's theorem_. In Resnick, the result was called _Scheffe's lemma_. I have found the result of Wikipedia in J. Yeh's book without itt being called anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146151/discussion-between-zhanxiong-and-user1865345).